# Webpack doesn't work when i use a simple url in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, vue.js, laravel-artisan

I use Laravel 5.5 to develop a WebApp, and Vuejs with webpack so means that i need to execute ***npm run dev***  to compile a app.js and app.css.

But this source files only works when i execute ***php artisan serve*** and NOT work when i access to my project by url

Eg:

```
php artisan serve : http://localhost:8000/admin > Works (app.js - app.css)

Traditional access: http://localhost/myProject/public/admin > Not Works
```

I really dont understand this. If have some documentation that explain me, please show me.

Thanks.

Comment: _"Traditional access"_ is not a traditional access, it depends on your own setup, which you're not providing.

Comment: How are you including those files in your html?

Comment: So, if i deploy this project in a host serve and i configure _/etc/sites-available/_  routing the public folder, and run npm run dev, i dont need ever use `php artisan serve` ? app.js and app.css would work fine?

Comment: @apokryfos  I include like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">`  And `<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>` in blade layout

Comment: Try using the url helper `{{url(mix('/css/app.css'))}}` . However you need to ensure your environment's `APP_URL` is set correctly and somehow adapts to the use case

Comment: For a Laravel set up you should be pointing a domain to the public directory of your app. For local development you can set up a vhost, or just keep using `php artisan serve`.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks!, thats works, now i only have a trouble with _api/call_ url, but that is more easy